# Can't use implemented namespace System.Windows

Tags: c#, user-controls, window

I have a UserControl with a context menu, when the user clicks on an item in the context menu I want to let another user dialog pop up. I designed a user dialog and searched for a method to let it pop up. I found the easy variant with:

```
Window myWindow = new Window { Title = "myTitle".. };
```

and then

```
myWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Then I implemented the reference to System.Windows and used the line:

```
using System.Windows;
```

But when I try to write my Code above Visual studio says type or namespace not found. I know that there could be an easy solution, but at the moment I can't find it.

### Update

After some time it worked. But only because Visual studio told me that the namespace is unclear. I had to write clearly System.Windows

But in the end I didn't know why Visual Studio told me this in the beginning, or why It didn't work from the beginning.

Comment: what platform are you using??

Comment: Window isn't even part of System.Windows;

Comment: Yes it is :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I use win10 as platform and vs for debugging.

Comment: Sorry I meant Winform, wpf, asp.net etc..

Comment: I use Usercontrol with Winform "A reusable Windows Forms control"
Is'nt it available in usercontrol?

Comment: I don't know why, but now I can use it. I didn't noticed that I changed anything.

Comment: Is your project a 'windows application' ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Windows application with user dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

For dialogs, you need to include:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry no, i implemented this by default. Still get the error.

Comment: Same as before, Type or Namespace couldn't be found