# C# Winforms: can't create window using system.windows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, namespaces, user-controls

This question is quite the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227557/cant-use-implemented-namespace-system-windows), but I can't find a suitable answer anywhere.
Basically, I'm trying to make a new window to show a user control but it doesn't work, it displays an error saying that the type or namespace "Window" could not be found. I have implemented `using System.Windows;`.
The code looks like this:

```
private void settB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = new Window
        {
            Title = "My User Control Dialog",
            Content = new qlSetting(),
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
        };
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to open a WPF window from a Windows Forms application?

Comment: Oh, you're right... I feel so dumb now. I didn't realize that the thread I saw this code on was about WPF.

Comment: Yeah, the person asking that one never tagged it as WPF so it's a little confusing. Window = WPF, Form = Windows Forms.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: No probs. Do you still need an answer as to how to do this?

Comment: Yeah, can I edit the question? I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes you can edit your question. Don't change it too much though. I've added an answer. Hopefully it's what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void settB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form window = new Form())
    {
        qlSetting ql = new qlSetting();
        ql.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        window.Controls.Add(ql);
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, is there a way to show only the user control and when a button there is clicked it goes back to the form?

Comment: Do you mean clicking a button on the user control or a button on the form?

Comment: Clicking a 'Back' button on the user control.

Comment: Yes. There are are a couple of ways of doing it. Making the Back button public and handling the Click event, or by having a custom event fired by the button which is hooked to when the usercontrol is created/added to the form.